# Updates on SQL Server CE 3.5 database .sdf not reflected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I am using C# VS2008, I looked at other questions related to this.

My problem is that any update using table adapters and datasets to the SQL Server CE database is not reflected in the database file.

Yes I am looking at `Root/bin/debug/xyz.sdf` file

Yes I also tried `DS.AcceptChanges()` method

I am opening the concerned sdf file using SdfBrowser (freeware) software

What could possibly go wrong?

```
//Instantiate dataset and TA
    ztATdbLocalDataSet1 assetInfoDS = new ztATdbLocalDataSet1();
    ztATdbLocalDataSet1TableAdapters.AssetInfoDataTableTableAdapter assetInfoTAdpt =     new ZTraka_App.ztATdbLocalDataSet1TableAdapters.AssetInfoDataTableTableAdapter();



try
            {
                assetInfoTAdpt.UpdateAssetMain(tag_id, asset_location, asset_category, asset_desc, asset_tag_created, asset_model, asset_quantity, asset_image, asset_comments, asset_id);
                assetInfoTAdpt.UpdateAssetInfoStat(tag_id, asset_lastchecked, asset_lastloc, asset_maint_due, tag_expiry, asset_status, asset_alarms, asset_value, asset_id);
                //assetInfoDS.AcceptChanges();

                textBlockTagNotifyMessage.Text = "Asset Info saved !";
                textBlockSearchWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
             }
```

EDIT: Updates...I just found out that the string parameter I pass in update method somehow mysteriously converts it to AnsiString (which is invalid data type for SQL CE databases)..
OK.I found the problem, now whats the solution?

Comment: please include some code at the heart of your problem.

Comment: `Free does not always mean better` but it would help if you would provide relevant code..

Comment: As a guess - keep in mind that data is pushed to the database file by SQL CE not immediately, but after flush interval specified in connection string. The default value is 10 sec. This is done for performance reasons.